# Enum class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, object, enums

Im trying to create an enum class with a type and a function that returns all the types.

Initially I have my enum in my object class and a function that returns these as an array:

```
class someClass: Mappable {

enum Type: Int {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    case C = 2
        }
    }
}

func getAllTypes() -> [Type] {
    return [Type.A, Type.B, Type.C]
}
}
```

The reason i want to extract this out of my object class is because this type is also used in other classes and i don't want to duplicate any unnecessary code.

I can manage to subclass the enum but not the function that returns all the types in an array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you might probably need to rename your `enum` as the `Type` is reserved for something else in a Swift _class_; and the class's name should be capitalised as well, like `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply add a static property to your enum Type?

```
enum Type: Int {
    case A = 0, B, C
    static let all = [A, B, C]
}
```

Comment: Since within the `enum` definition, you can omit `.` for all cases in the array (i.e., `... = [A, B, C]`).

Comment: This is the one i have used. Thanks @appzYourLife

Answer (score 4):

#### Initialize `all` using an executed-one-time-only closure and `AnyGenerator`

[@vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896266/4573247) showed how to initialize the `all` array in a generalized manner using an executed-one-time-only closure in combination with the failable `init(rawValue:)` initialer of `enum`'s. A slight variation of the method in the fore mentioned answer is to exchange the explicit `while` loop and array appending with an `AnyGenerator`:

```
enum Type: Int {
    case A = 0, B, C, D, E, F, G, H

    static let all: [Type] = {
        var rValue = 0
        return AnyGenerator<Type> {
            defer { rValue += 1 }
            return Type(rawValue: rValue)
        }.map{$0}
    }()
}

print(Type.all) 
    // [Type.A, Type.B, Type.C, Type.D, Type.E, Type.F, Type.G, Type.H]
```

This works under the condition that `rawValue`'s are simply `++` increasing (`0, 1, 2, ...`).

---

#### Initialize `all` by conforming the `enum` to `SequenceType`

As another alternative, since your `rawValue`'s are integer-wise sequential (`++`), you could let your `enum` conform to `SequenceType`, in which case the array of all cases can be easily generated simply by using `.map`

```
enum Type: Int, SequenceType {
    case A = 0, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
    
    init() { self = A } // Default (first) case intializer
    
    /* conform Type to SequenceType (here: enables only 
       simple (self.rawValue)...last traversing) */
    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<Type> {
        var rValue = self.rawValue
        return AnyGenerator {
            defer { rValue += 1 }
            return Type(rawValue: rValue)
        }
    }
    
    /* use the fact that Type conforms to SequenceType to neatly
     initialize your static all array */
     static let all = Type().map { $0 }
}

print(Type.all) 
    // [Type.A, Type.B, Type.C, Type.D, Type.E, Type.F, Type.G, Type.H]
```

Applying this conformance *only* to initialize the static `all` array is possibly overkill, but a plausible alternative in case you'd like to be able to able to use other aspects of your `enum` conforming to `SequenceType`

```
for typeCase in Type() {
    // treat each type ...
    print(typeCase, terminator: " ")
} // A B C D E F G H

for caseFromEAndForward in Type.E {
    print(caseFromEAndForward, terminator: " ")
} // E F G H
```

---

#### Using `flatMap` to initialize cases based on a range of `rawValue`'s

Finally, as a variation of [@appzYourLife neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38894766/4573247), in case you have very many cases, you can use a `flatMap` operation on the range of `rawValue`'s to initialize the static `allValues` array, e.g.

```
enum Type: Int {
    case A = 0, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
    static let all = (A.rawValue...H.rawValue)
       .flatMap{ Type(rawValue: $0) }
}

print(Type.all) 
    // [Type.A, Type.B, Type.C, Type.D, Type.E, Type.F, Type.G, Type.H]
```

There's, however, not really any practical use for this method as the general size methods ([@vacawama:s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38896266/4573247) or the `SequenceType` above) would always be preferable for enums of many cases. The possibly use case I can see for this is if the `rawValue`'s of the different cases are sequential *but not simply by `++`*, e.g. if the `rawValue`'s are used for some bitmasking

```
// ...
case A = 0, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8, E = 16, F = 32, G = 64, H = 128
```

The method above would use a method of brute-forcing through the range of `rawValue`'s, where a minority will actually correspond to actual cases. Somewhat wasteful, but since it's a one-time static initialization, that shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: Nice solution. I changed `var` into `let` since the `all` array won't change after compilation. I hope someday Swift will provide an automatic way to retrieve all the values into an enum.

Comment: @appzYourLife Ah yes, will update here as well, thanks! In this context, I believe using the explicit cases as in your solution is way better though (since we have them all in the definition above anyway :) ), but _if_ we could retrieve the rawValue range of an enum, then perhaps the `flatMap` solution could be more useful (or, in another context: perhaps if we need this in an external function outside of the enum definition).

Comment: @dfri Your solution is also viable. Thanks. Altho i used the above as I don't have many types :)

Comment: In your `flapMap` example, you could use the range `(A.rawValue...H.rawValue)` to eliminate the magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If your `rawValue`s are sequential `Int`s, you can take advantage of the fact that the `Type(rawValue:)` initializer will fail and return `nil` for illegal values to compute `Type.all` automatically without having to explicitly list the values or set the range.  If you add more cases to your enum, it will automatically adjust:

```
enum Type: Int {
    case A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K
    static let all: [Type] = {
        var all: [Type] = []
        var value = 0
        while let e = Type(rawValue: value) {
            all.append(e)
            value += 1
        }
        return all
    }()
}

print(Type.all)
```

> ```
> [Type.A, Type.B, Type.C, Type.D, Type.E, Type.F, Type.G, Type.H, Type.I, Type.J, Type.K]
> ```

Comment: Neat! Might be worth pointing out (to future readers of this thread) that this (as well as my own solution) works under the condition the `rawValue`:s are simply `++` sequential (e.g. no bitmasking `1, 2, 4, ...` or similar rawValues).

Comment: I wont include this in my own answer since cleverly using a executed-one-time-only closure was the idea of this answer, but note that also here you may alternatively [make use of `AnyGenerator`](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/bbbdd16a872a9d94282257b3fb3b57c4) for a (possibly) slightly more neat version of the above.

Comment: @dfri, go ahead and use the executed-one-time-only closure for your answer.  The goal is to produce the best answer, and iterating on other's answers frequently produces better answers.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5

Now you have `CaseIterable`. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable). [Another topic](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/getting-all-cases-of-an-enum/).

> Types that conform to the CaseIterable protocol are typically
>   enumerations without associated values. When using a CaseIterable
>   type, you can access a collection of all of the type’s cases by using
>   the type’s allCases property.

```
enum Direction: CaseIterable {
  case left
  case right
  case up
  case down
}

Direction.allCases.count
Direction.allCases.forEach { print($0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a static array that contains all possible values of enum:

```
static let allValues = [A, B, C]
```

Then you can use it where you want as :

```
var allEnumValues = Type.allValues
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is used in other classes as well then don't put it inside a class

```
class YourClass : Mappable {

}

enum Type: Int {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    case C = 2
        }
    }
}
```